# Loading data into MySQL database using cron

Tags: mysql, cron

I would like to make the loading of data into MySQL database (Ubuntu 12.04) a cron job. I have am able to do it manually using the code:

```
LOAD LOCAL DATA 
INFILE re.txt
INTO table rasss
LINES TERMINATED BY '|'
```

I also know how to add a job to the `crontab -e` file, but I have only done so for single line commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the best solution would be to make a short script of this, and call that script from `cron` -- you could do it as a one-liner, but it would be ugly and hard to maintain, and there's no advantage to be had.  (let me know if you need an example)

**edit:**

try something along these lines, off the top of my head:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_USER='my_user';
DB_PASSWD='passwd';

DB_NAME='db_name';
TABLE='rass';

INPUT_FILE='/full/path/to/re.txt';

SQL="USE $DB_NAME; LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE '$INPUT_FILE' REPLACE INTO TABLE `$TABLE` LINES TERMINATED BY '|' CHARACTER SET utf8;"
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD --default_character_set utf8 $DB_NAME -e "$SQL"
```

As for where to put it, well, that's up to you.  Bear in mind that if you use the root `crontab` then the script will execute with root permissions, and must be owned by `root` (and not be world-writable).  For this reason, I sometimes have scripts of this kind in `/root`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes i would be grateful for an example, if i make a script, where do i store it

Comment: @sosytee -- see update :)

Comment: I have the idea, now will work on the coding